# Stop flashing Div while URL refresh

Tags: jquery

While refreshing **register** div, first I am getting **login** div flash and then displaying **register** div.I want to stop flashing of **login** div

For that purpose,I am using `jQuery`as

```
jQuery(window).load('http:\\localhost:8080\MyPrimeJq\login.html#toregister', function () {
    jQuery('#login').removeAttr('login')
});
```

But this is not working

Comment: hide it initially and make it display after the page got loaded? I am really not sure what you are asking

Comment: On refreshing above mentioned url, first its blinking login div and then going to register div which are in the same login.html page..